# Android SD card encryption

Tags: encryption

I was looking at some encryption standards and was wondering, what kind of encryption algorithm does Android's SD card encryption use? Is it AES 128 or a different algorithm?

Comment: Android uses adoptable storage to encrypt SD card. AES-XTS-256 to encrypt files and AES-CBC-CTR-256 to encrypt filenames.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that it would use AES 128 due to performance limitations.